# Absolute Value Equivalence relation inequality Question

Tags: inequality, equivalence-relations, absolute-value, binary-operations

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly to do to see if the following relation is symmetric and transitive. I've already determined that it is reflexive. Could someone please help me?

For $a, b \in \Bbb R$, define $a \sim b$ if $ |a - b| \leq 1$. Is the relation $\sim$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive? Is $\sim$ an equivalence relation?

Thank you!

Comment: But it is reflexive! $a$ ~ $a$ because $|a-a|=0 \leq 1$

Comment: For transitivity, draw a picture. Or think about your neighbor to the right, and *his* neighbor to the right.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that it IS reflexive. However, I'm having trouble proving/disproving symmetry and transitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=3$, then we have $a \sim b$ because $|1-2|=1\leq 1$ and we also have $b \sim c$ because $|2-3|=1\leq 1$. However it is **not** true that $a \sim c$ because $|1-3|=2\ge 1$. That is a counter example for transitivity, thus this relation is not an equivalence relation.

For the future: For absolute values, try imagining a number line in your head where you need to place two numbers and the $|a-b|\leq 1$ means that the distance between them is less than 1. From there, you can develop your argument.

By the way, this relation is symmetric: If $a \sim b$ then $|a-b|\leq 1$ but notice that $|a-b|=|(-1)(b-a)|=|-1||b-a|=|b-a|$ so $|b-a|\leq 1$ as well and $b \sim a$.